My mediawiki application is adding duplicate utf-8 charset in headers for static files
I'm very new to mediawiki framework and recently I'm facing a very weird issue.
For all my css and js files, I'm duplicate charset UTF-8 in headers.
Please see below screenshots
The same thing is happening for static JS files as well.
I'm very confused. I tried few things like in LocalSettings.php file, I've added
 $wgLegacyEncoding = 'ISO-8859-1';

but still the same.
I'm using apache and in httpd.conf file, this code is already there
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

now not sure where to change. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Looks like those are static resources delivered directly by the web server; so you should investigate in the direction of web server configuration, rather than mediawiki's PHP code & settings, I suppose.

The HTTP header should read as Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8 so where come from the charset: utf-8 item with a colon and space instead of Equals Sign?
